What winding geometry maximizes inductance, but minimizes stray field and resistance for air-core inductors?
I want to make an air-core inductor with about 1 mH of inductance. All dicussion below is based on online calculators, such as these ones for wire loops and toroids.
At first, I considered how to achieve maximum inductance with minimum length of wire, and thus minimum resistance. The result is to basically make a small loop of many tightly coupled turns.
Unfortunately, this geometry causes a large dipolar magnetic field, which might be a problem for equipment near the wire loop. So, in order to minimize the stray field, I considered an air-core toroid.
I noticed, that the necessary wire length for the toroid is at least 3-4 times as long as for the simple many-turn loop. And of course, toroids are also difficult to wind.
Are there other geometries than a toroid that strongly attenuate the dipolar farfield, while achieving 1 mH with shorter wire than a toroidal geometry?

Are sure that many small loops have shorter wire length than one big loop for same inductance?

@Rokta yes, if the loops are mutually coupled.

Why do you want to avoid a ferromagnetic core of any kind?

(I don't know the 1st thing about inductors. Not even why toroidal wouldn't cut it even without core - at least re stray field. I'd start with outer diameter = winding diameter = inner diameter (doughnut?).)

@Andyaka It's a gut feeling because it's for a kA current application and I need rather constant L (over I). But I may have neglected F cores too soon with too little consideration. I will at least calculate whether some low mu toroids might be suitable.

I'm afraid you can't -- though, this is far from a proof, and I would be interested to see (a) counterexample(s).  A qualitative argument thus follows.
Current and magnetic field lines are crossed.  Any way the field goes, current goes perpendicular, and vice versa.  In a solenoid, current goes around and around cylindrically, and field goes through (and out the ends, into considerable fringing field as noted).  Field inevitably takes a longer path (through, then out and back around the coil), in a toroidal geometry; though, the path length may be long, but the cross-sectional area is large as well, so the inductivity is not particularly low, after integrating the effect of these parameters over all space.
The complementary geometry, is a toroidal coil with circular field geometry.  This keeps the magnetic path length short, but the cross-sectional area is relatively small as well, and the wire length is higher (depending on fill factor of the toroid, anyway, but that is itself another open variable).
I would posit that there are no other interesting geometries, only the dual pair as above.  Anything else can be seen as a partial cancelling-out of one or another aspect, a mutation that costs either more path length or wire length; or, that isn't symmetrical.  (It stands to reason that rotational symmetry, and perhaps cylindrical or toroidal as well, is the optimal case; square corners are just going to cost extra wire length, for example.  This is another assumption to be proven, of course.)
To minimize wire length while maximizing magnetic field (strength, energy, volume -- take your pick, optimality is likely an application-specific combination of all of these), you certainly can't be spending any wire length canceling out external magnetic fields: that specifically reduces inductance while increasing length.
A more experienced field solver, or topologist, might have an argument to the effect of: a toroid is a superposition of solenoids, and thus exhibits precisely this cancellation, hence it must have X times more winding length per scaled inductance factor.  There might also be a way to continuously transform between circular-toroidal and vice versa (heh, or maybe strictly not, in the sense that one cannot comb a sphere; or that one cannot turn one inside out -- except through significant and specific contortions thereof, that is), and thus arrive at a sort of continuum proof.
On a more practical note, it is peculiar why you're asking about air-core inductors in the first place; perhaps for physical reasons (field strength alone, without concern for field geometry..?), perhaps electrical (coreless = no saturation and distortion to deal with), perhaps purely out of curiosity for the scenario.  So, not discounting that, out of hand.  But also to say: there are other, better (read: practical) solutions to such a problem; you can put a ferrite (or powdered iron, or at low frequencies, sheet or plate) shield around the coil, to return those external field lines quicker (short-circuiting them, in a sense), which increases the inductivity as well as greatly reducing external field (intensity-wise, and raising impedance so that less current is induced in nearby conductors too), and because it's around the outside, the path width is wide so not much shield thickness is needed for typical flux density levels (i.e., it's relatively cheap to avoid saturation, at least to a point).
Even inductors for pulsed operation aren't soooo terrible to design around a core; but things do get pretty limited as the duty cycle dips into the single-percent range, say.  That is, where flux density might be over 1T at the coil itself, at such currents where the coil is heating up quite rapidly indeed, but only for some milliseconds before it gets anywhere close to melting.  Magnetizers, TMS, electromagnetic forming, etc. are typical applications.  For less strenuous applications, cores are still attractive to save on space, external field, and perhaps cost (trading copper for core costs).
Without going into design detail, I will leave this trick: the effective or average permeability of the core and winding geometry is inversely related to winding resistance, and higher resistance is generally tolerable in pulsed applications.  For copper around room temperature, in continuous duty, we generally want µeff around 30-100 (and hence this is typical of the majority of commercially-available materials and gapped cores).  For higher resistance (say we didn't have copper and had to deal with pure iron or something), µ ≥ 200 might be optimal.  For pulsed application, higher losses are typically acceptable, and so lower permeability in given size.  µ = 10 is commercially available in toroid form (Micrometals mix #2), or can be made from ferrite pieces or shapes (an open-face, low-profile 'E' typically places around here).  Rod cores are adjustable by way of length to diameter ratio (L/D in the 1-4 range giving µ ~ 3-10), and any material with µr ≫ µeff will do.

You are right. The two geometries (loop and toroid) are actually converse cases of the same topology. Good point. That makes it appear more likely to me, as you described any other geometry will be a trade-off. Note my comment to Andy above regarding magnetic cores.  A quick check indicated that even large low-mu cores wouldn't work very likely.

kA need large area cores, and single turns; still, it's not unreasonable to have a core at such currents: a pair of ferrite plates around a busbar, for example (the thickness of the busbar is likely enough air gap, no 'U' shape required), or better yet powdered or laminated iron (frequency allowing).

A general geometry that will allow you to vary the order of the far field drop off, while not losing too much inductance and contribution from mutual inductance would be to use anti-parallel solenoids. You would need either a field solver, or to have better command of Biot Savart and integration than I do to calculate what the actual inductance will be, given the many variables of solenoid length, O/D, I/D and configuration.
Using asciiart, the first few configurations of increasing order are as follows, using rows of Pascal's triangle for the alternating weights, always adding up to zero for first order.
--1-->    --1-->    --1-->
<--1--    <--2--    <--3--
          --1-->    --3-->
                    <--1--

That's in 2D, with a linear set of solenoids. Stacking 4, or maybe better 6, compensating '1' strength solenoids around a '4' or '6' strength central one might also be worth evaluating.
I would not be surprised if the first +/- 1 configuration of just 2 solenoids eventually wins out in terms of inductor quality for size and far-field.
A uniformly-wound toroid has zero external field everywhere. Two anti-parallel solenoids are simply a very non-uniformly-wound toroid, sacrificing near field zerosity (?) for easier winding and (I  expect) winding length.
It might be the case that for two anti-parallel solenoids, winding them on semi-circular formers, to allow their adjacent turns to be closer together, will maximise the mutual inductance and hence Q factor for any length of wire. In the toroid view, this is equivalent to reducing the central hole diameter, which increases the magnetic path area and reduces its length, both increasing the inductance.
I am sure your definition of 'near' and 'far' will affect the optimum coil shape. With anti-parallel coils, the dipole far field is zero, to be replaced by the quadrapole field, which drops off more quickly.
As you comment, another option is to construct an easier-to-wind approximation to a toroid from a number of short solenoids arranged in a circle. This is much closer to a 'uniformly-wound' toroid, will have better near field than a pair of anti-parallel solenoids, and a higher order far field drop off. However, the physical arrangement requires a fairly large 'central-hole' diameter (in the toroid view, lower mutual inductance in the discrete solenoids view), which limits the inductance and hence Q you can achieve. Only you know the relative weightings of your Q versus size versus far-field versus complexity constraints, to choose between two side-by-side, and more in-a-circle coil configurations.

Your approach of "solenoid lego" just made me have the idea, that I could just take several identical solenoids and make a 4-sided "toroid" out of 4 of them (or 3 or 6 or whatever). I will still have to consider what will trade better in terms of manufacturability and resistance for a given far-field dropoff. Thanks for this idea!
